# Role of a person in charge of the casting of a film

Tags: vocabulary

Let's say this is the information related to a film:

> **Written by:** John Doe
>   **Produced by:** Mary James
>   **Casting by:** Peter Smith, Sarah Jones
>   ...

Then:

- John Doe is a **writer**.
- Mary James is a **producer**.
- Peter Smith and Sarah Jones are **...** ?

Comment: Would this be better suited to the Movies and TV site?

Comment: **Castors**!  No, wait...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They are **casting directors**.

> For some major productions, the process of selecting actors for sometimes hundreds of parts may often require specialized staff. While the last word remains with the people in charge, artistic and production, a **casting director** or "CD" (and sometimes the casting associate) is in charge of most of the daily work involved in this process during pre-production.

~ [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casting_(performing_arts)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casting%5f%28performing%5farts%29)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But director suggests to me a single person... If we have 4 people in the **casting by** list, does it make sense that all of them are casting directors?

Comment: @MikO Yes it does make sense. You have more than one casting director in large scale productions because there are thousands of potential applicants, as well as the main characters you need to cast all the support roles and the extras.

Comment: Many movies credit a **Casting Agency** (such as the [C.S.A](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casting_Society_of_America)), if the group of casting directors are incorporated.